# How to replace a text/string in a file with another text/string using python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written the below code to replace the string "YANTRAPRODPATH" with "YantraProd1" in a file and save it:-

```
fileToModify = open("C:/workspace/PROD/bat1/customer_overrides.properties",'r+')
textToSearch = "<YANTRAPRODPATH>"
textToReplace = "YantraProd1"

f = fileinput.FileInput(fileToModify, inplace=True, backup='.bak')

for line in f:
    print(line.replace(textToSearch, textToReplace))

f.close()
```

But I am getting below error:-

```
C:\workspace>python c:/workspace/ReplaceText.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/workspace/ReplaceText.py", line 20, in <module>
    for line in f:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\fileinput.py", line 237, in next
    line = self._readline()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\fileinput.py", line 316, in _readline
    os.rename(self._filename, self._backupfilename)
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

Am I missing something here? And is there a more simpler way to do this?

Comment: The error message does seem to indicate a different line than the ones you posted: os.rename(self._filename, self._backupfilename)

Comment: @mrCarnivore can you read traceback?

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo: I think so. And as it says: the most recent call last. This would mean the most recent call (the one that caused the error) is the one where the author wants to rename a file. Which is not in the printout above. Am I missing something?

Comment: @mrCarnivore Yes, you are missing something. The traceback says: In line 20 of`c:/workspace/ReplaceText.py` `f.__iter__()` method was called (implicitly by `for line in f`) and in this method in line 237 of `C:\Python27\lib\fileinput.py` method `self._readline()` was called and in this method in line 316 `os.rename()` function was called and inside this funcion exception of type `WindowsError` was raised. `os.rename()` is the most recent call but it was triggered by `for line f:` via the chain of calls listed in the traceback.

Answer (score 1):

`FileInput` constructor expects filename or list of filenames and not `file` object.

```
fileToModify = "C:/workspace/PROD/bat1/customer_overrides.properties"
textToSearch = "<YANTRAPRODPATH>"
textToReplace = "YantraProd1"

f = fileinput.FileInput(fileToModify, inplace=True, backup='.bak')

for line in f:
    print(line.replace(textToSearch, textToReplace))

f.close()
```